# return static array in a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have this function

```
int* ftab(int n)
 {
  static int tab[2];
   tab[0] = n;
   tab[1] = n+1;
   return tab;
   }

 void caller()
  {
   int* tab = ftab(3); // it gives me correct result
   int * tab=ftab(2)  // but when I use another time it makes incorrect 
                         answer
 }
```

It gives me the correct answer only the first time only in the first call but in the other calls it is not correct. I don't know why, thanks for help.

Comment: What is "not correct" about it?

Comment: static int tab[2]; is executed exactly one time, the first time you call the function.

Comment: When I call it multiple time it gives me correct result only for the first call ,the second call ,the third call and other call incorrect result.

Comment: I want to call this function many time not only one time.  I want to execute it multiple time

Comment: @kais: One final attempt before I give up: what is the "incorrect result"? What result were you expecting? What result did you get?

Comment: I would expect that the last call will have "correct" result as the array values are changed for each call and all return values point to the same array. Last one rules...

Comment: @nicomp `static int tab[2];` is only the array definition, it's not executed at all...

Comment: since the array declared within `ftab` is `static`, it means that it has the same address all the time. Reusing the array doesn't work you have to make a copy. It's much better to return an allocated array, or use an output parameter to fill it in

Comment: it isn't c++11 related, or even c++. Looks like a pure C question to me.

Comment: I tested the first call it give me correct answer int* tab = ftab(3) : tab[0]=3 ; tab[1]=4 ; when I call it this function another time tab[0] and tab[1] are not correct. I dont know it return correct result only for the first call.I dont know there is any problem of memory ?

Comment: How can I execute it many times

Comment: Please provide a full example where you print the values.

Comment: static array is executed only one time ?

Comment: @SisterFister You're confusing declaration and definition

Comment: @nicomp Maybe, but I still think nothing is executed there...

Comment: @kais This question was closed because you didn't tell us why the second call is incorrect.  If you want the question to be reopened, you need to edit the question telling us what output you expected to get and what output (cut and paste this part) you actually got.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cleaned-up version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *ftab(int n)
{
    static int tab[2];
    tab[0] = n;
    tab[1] = n+1;
    return tab;
}

int main()
{
    int *tab1 = ftab(3);
    printf("first: %d %d\n", tab1[0], tab1[1]);

    int *tab2 = ftab(2);
    printf("second: %d %d\n", tab2[0], tab2[1]);

    printf("but first is now: %d %d\n", tab1[0], tab1[1]);
 }
```

First it prints

```
first: 3 4
```

which is the right answer for a call to `ftab(3)`.

Then it prints

```
second: 2 3
```

which is the right answer for a call to `ftab(2)`.

But then it prints

```
but first is now: 2 3
```

The answer to the first call changed behind our backs!  How can that be?

And the answer, of course, is that the array `tab[]` inside the function `ftab()` is static.  There's exactly one copy of it.  It gets reused every time you call `ftab`.  The previous contents are overwritten by each new call.

You can see more clearly what's going on if you also print out the pointer values that `ftab` is returning.  If I change `main` to this:

```
int main()
{
    int *tab1 = ftab(3);
    printf("first: %p: %d %d\n", tab1, tab1[0], tab1[1]);
    int *tab2 = ftab(2);
    printf("second: %p: %d %d\n", tab2, tab2[0], tab2[1]);
    printf("but first is now: %p: %d %d\n", tab1, tab1[0], tab1[1]);
 }
```

now it prints

```
first: 0x10b35e018: 3 4
second: 0x10b35e018: 2 3
but first is now: 0x10b35e018: 2 3
```

So `ftab` is returning the *exact same pointer value every time!*  How can that be?  And the answer is, it's always returning a pointer to the same static array `tab`, but it's filling in the array with different values each time.

There are several lessons here:

1. Functions can't return arrays.
2. A function can return a pointer to a static array, but it's an imperfect substitute.
3. When a function returns a pointer to a static array, you do not want to save a copy of that pointer and use it later, because the result may get overwritten by another call to the function.
4. A pointer is not an array.  A pointer can point to an array, but the contents of that array can change out from under the pointer.
5. When using pointers, you have to keep clear in your mind the distinction between *the pointer* and *what the pointer points to*.  This code provides a perfect example of that distinction.  Do the calls `ftab(2)` and `ftab(3)` return the same thing, or different things?  Well, they return the same *pointer*, but after each call, *what that pointer points to* is different.

Answer (score 1):

You must turn warnings of your compiler on. It will tell you what is wrong:

```
   int *tab = ftab(3);
   int *tab = ftab(2);
```

Your second `int *tab` is an error because `tab` is already declared. The statement also had an error in that it had no terminating semi-colon. So, your compiler made something of it and you see an error. How do you see an error? I see no print statements.

The following should work perfectly fine:

```
   int *tab= ftab(3);
   printf("%d, %d\n", tab[0], tab[1]);
   ftab(2);
   printf("%d, %d\n", tab[0], tab[1]);
```

Note that in the second call you don't need an assignment as `tab` is already pointing to the static array. It only got new values.